# Convert all doubles to integers for better performance, is it just a rumor?

Tags: c++, performance, math, integer, double

I have a very complicated and sophisticated data fitting program which uses the Levenverg-Marquardt algorithm to do fitting in double precision (basically the fitting class is templatized, but I use instantiate it to doubles). The fitting process involves:

- Calculating an error function (chi-square)
- Solving a system of linear equations (I use lapack for that)
- calculating the derivatives of a function with respect to the parameters, which I want to fit to the data (usually 20+ parameters)
- calculating the function value continuously: the function is a complicated combination of a sinusoidal and exponential functions with a few harmonics.

A colleague of mine has suggested that I use integers for at least 10 times faster at least. My questions are:

1. Is that true that I will get that kind of improvement?
2. Is it safe to convert everything to integers? And what are the drawbacks to this?
3. What advice would you have for this whole issue? What would you do?

The program is developed to calculate some parameters from the signal online, which means that the program must be as fast as possible, but I'm wondering whether it's worth it to start the project of converting everything to integers.

Comment: Have you profiled the code to see where it's spending most of the time?

Comment: On a modern x86 processor, it is unlikely to make a difference. [Proof by Alexandrescu](http://vimeo.com/55639112).

Comment: @NPE Yes. Most of the time is spend in calculating sines, cosines and at matrix inversion (solving the linear system).

Comment: 1.: propably not, because of 2.: As you already stated the Levenberg-Marquardt-Algorihm needs the derivatives of the objective functions. But the function with integer output is much more non-smooth than that one with double-output. That can lead to convergence failure or to drastic increas of the number of Newton-Gauss-iterations 3.: Use algorithmic ways to speed up. For instance fast Broyden-update of the Jacobian.

Comment: One example we've had that definately made a difference was with a sparc processor (Sun Microsystems).  It had 8 cores, but only one FPP.  Which meant that all floating point operations had to go through one operation.  So when we moved to an `int` solution, it made a tremendous difference. But this is VERY specific to the hardware.

Comment: In that case I guess ints will be slower unless there are optimized sine/cosine functions for integers.

Comment: Have you considered building a static table of these sines, cosines and inversions?

Comment: @JohnDibling Yes. But I need full precision since I'm doing a precision measurement.

Comment: You may try to use floats. It might reduce cache misses, without transcoding all the code to integer arithmetics. I often do optimization, 99% of the time it's just useless early optim. Don't be that guy ^^

Comment: Why does your need for full precision preclude the possibility of pre-computing the values?  Because of memory constraints?

Comment: @JohnDibling Yes. A table for a full cycle cosine will take a lot of memory.

Comment: Can you quantify "a lot?"

Comment: @ndj floats aren't precise enough. Our signal to noise (SNR) is ~ 10^8.

Comment: Also, have you considered porting to a many-core architecture, such as CUDA?

Comment: @JohnDibling I'm using currently a 64-core machine with AMD processors. Moving to a CUDA or Intel Phi would be a very big change to the current system.

Comment: @Physicist:It looks like it is a tracking problem. Isn't it?

Comment: @user2708138 tracking problem?

Answer (score 6):

The amount of improvement depends on your platform.  For example, if your platform has a fast floating point coprocessor, performing arithmetic in floating point may be faster than integral arithmetic.

You may be able to get more performance gain by optimizing your algorithms rather than switching to integer arithmetic.

Another method for boosting performance is to reduce data cache hits and also reducing branches and loops.

**I would measure performance of the program to find out where the bottlenecks are** and then review the sections that where most of the performance takes place.  For example, in my embedded system, micro-optimizations like what you are suggesting, saved 3 microseconds.  This gain is not worth the effort to retest the entire system.  If it works, don't fix it.  Concentrate on correctness and robustness first.

Answer (score 2):

First, this reeks of attempting to optimize unnecessarily.

Second, `doubles` are a minimum of 64-bits.  `ints` on most systems are 32-bits.  So you have a couple of choices:  truncate the double (which reduces your precision to a single), or store it in the space of 2 integers, or store it as an `unsigned long long` (which is at least 64-bits as well).  For the first 2 options, you are facing a performance hit as you must convert the numbers back and forth between the doubles you are operating on and the integers you are storing it as.  For the third option, you are not gaining any performance increase (in terms of memory usage) as they are basically the same size - so you'd just be converting them to integers for no reason.

So, to get to your questions:

1) Doubtful, but you can try it to see for yourself.

2) The problem isn't storage as the bits are just bits when they get into memory.  The problem is the arithmetic.  Since you stated you need double precision, attempting to do those operations on an integer type will not give you the results you are looking for.

3)  Don't optimize until it has been proven something needs to have a performance improvement.  And always remember Amdahl's Law:  Make the common case fast and the rare case correct.

Answer (score 2):

The bottom line here is that you have to test it and decide for yourself.  Profile a release build using real data.

> 1- Is that true that I will get that kind of improvement?

Maybe yes, maybe no.  It depends on a number of factors, such as

1. How long it takes to convert from `double` to `int`
2. How big a word is on your machine
3. What platform/toolset you're using and what optimizations you have enabled
4. (Maybe) how big a cache line is on your platform
5. How fast your memory is
6. How fast your platform computes floating-point versus integer.

And who knows what else.  In short, too many complex variables for anyone to be able to say *for sure* if you will or will not improve performance.

But I would be highly skeptical about your friend's claim, "at least 10 times faster at least."

> 2- Is it safe to convert everything to integers? And what are the
>   drawbacks to this?

It depends on what you're converting and how.  Obviously converting a value like `123.456` to an integer is decidedly unsafe.

Drawbacks include loss of precision, loss of accuracy, and the expense in terms of space and time to actually do the conversions.  Another significant drawback is the fact that you have to write a substantial amount of code, and every line of code you write is a probable source of new bugs.

> 3- What advice would you have for this whole issue? What would you do?

I would step back & take a deep breath.  Profile your code under real-world conditions.  Identify the sources of the bottlenecks.  Find out what the *real* problems are, and if there even are any.

Identify inefficiencies in your algorithms, and fix them.

Throw hardware at the problem.

Then you can endeavor to start micro-optimizing.  This would be my last resort, especially if the optimization technique you are considering would require writing a lot of code.

Comment: About the claim of converting 123.456; Of course the conversion will be smart to take precision into account and make 123.456 -> 123456000000 maybe (or some similar move).

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist:  OK, I just wanted to make sure that you were aware.

Comment: As I commented already above: Just don't do it. Levenberg Marquardt lives from convergence. There you need the exponential capabilities of the floating point format. If you do not constraint yourself to a constant number of iterations and maybe very strange results you will be punished with convergence failure or long iterations.

Comment: @user2708138 I completely agree with you; but I'm listening to different opinions :)

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist:  As you are probably gathering, we don't know nearly enough about your actual implementation & environment to give you any real, *actionable* advice -- only general suggestions.  All of which might be inappropriate for you because of your actual environment.  My best suggestion is to identify hostspots, and tune those individual functions to within an inch of their life before making some drastic change in the hopes of finding some magical silver bullet.  We can help with the tuning if the scope is not onerous.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is:

First tune it in single-thread mode (by the [*random-pausing method*](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262)) until you can't find any way to reduce cycles. The kinds of things I've found are:

- a large fraction of time spent in library functions like `sin`, `cos`, `exp`, and `log` where the arguments were often unchanged, so the answers would be the same. The solution for that is called "memoizing", where you figure out a place to store old values of arguments and results, and check there first before calling the function.
- In calling library functions like DGEMM (lapack matrix-multiply) that one would assume are optimized to the teeth, they are actually spending a large fraction of time calling a function to determine if the matrices are upper or lower triangle, square, symmetric, or whatever, rather than actually doing the multiplication. If so, the answer is obvious - write a special routine just for your situation.

Don't say "but I don't have those problems". Of course - you probably have different problems - but the process of finding them is the same.

Once you've made it as fast as possible in single-thread, then figure out how to parallelize it. Multi-threading can have high overhead, so it's best not to tightly-couple the threads.

Regarding your question about converting from doubles to integers, the other answers are right on the money. It only makes sense in very particular situations.